# Are there any known weaknesses in the Stellar Consensus Protocol?

Tags: security, consensus, scp

Are there any known situations, although infrequent or difficult to meet, where the Stellar Consensus protocol could not work well or where the network can be attacked by malicious nodes?

Comment: Anyone looking to answer should take a look at this https://www.stellar.org/papers/stellar-consensus-protocol.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer is here, but I'd like to know more: 
https://rubin.io/public/pdfs/oort.pdf

> Two open problems in Stellar are the mechanism by which quorums are chosen (peer selection) and how new arguments may be proposed such that contention is low (i.e. avoid dueling proposers).

and

> Stellar consensus can be extremely inefficient in terms of number of messages
>   sent, especially with dueling proposers.

Comment: Maybe that pdf is outdated? (Wrote on May 8, 2015) - 
On stellar site the SCP whitepaper is dated February 25, 2016
https://www.stellar.org/papers/stellar-consensus-protocol.pdf

Comment: It shouldn't,  as it is referring to the original whitepaper from Mazieres, the SCP creator. I don't know if the protocol has been modified afterwards.

Comment: @Almaxia Prof DM's SCP paper has been modified quite a few times, [a Chinese translation version](https://github.com/StellarCN/scp_zh/commits/master?after=27216301d7a233296b0a744a16445c037f2d3c16+69) was released before Sep/4/2015.

Answer (score 0):

[*Is Stellar As Secure As You Think?*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.13302.pdf) from 2019 suggests some weaknesses:

> According  to  our  results,  all nodes  get  stuck  after  only  two  nodes  fail.  This  implies  that, currently (Jan. 2019), the value of x in Stellar is approximately 4.5 (≈2/44×100), where the total number of active validators is
> 44 and f is 2. To make matters worse, the two nodes that cause the entire system to be stuck are run by the same organization, namely  the  Stellar  foundation,  making  Stellar  vulnerable  to “single point of failures”. In summary, our contributions are as follows:

> 1. We analyze FBA and prove that it is not superior to PBFT in terms of safety and liveness.
> 2. We  conduct  a  data  analysis  on  the  Stellar  system,  and show  that  the  structure  of  quorum  slices  is  highly  centralized.
> 3. We   study   cascading   failures   considering   the   current quorum  slices.  Our  results  imply  that  validators  cannot achieve a consensus after deleting only two nodes run by the Stellar foundation.

A subsequent paper from the SDF, [Fast and secure global payments with Stellar](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/%7Edm/home/papers/lokhava:stellar-core.pdf) addresses these concerns:

> However, nodes’ configurations were such that liveness (though not safety) depended on us, the Stellar Development Foundation (SDF); had SDF suddenly disappeared, other node operator swould have needed to intervene and manually remove us from quorum slices for the network to continue.

> While we and many others want to reduce SDF’s systemic importance, this goal received increasing priority after researchers [58] quantified and publicized the network’s centralization without differentiating the risks to safety and liveness. A number of operators reacted with active configuration adjustments, primarily increasing the size of their quorum slices in an effort to dilute SDF’s importance; ironically this only increased the risk to liveness.